# In arabic, is the word salat (or salah, not sure), meaning the muslim prayer was there before islam, or did islam introduced the word?

Tags: salat

Peace everyone. As a quranist i believe that Quran contains all the islamic details. Allah says in the Quran to do salat, so i was wondering if the word salat was there before Quran?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **Yes**. This is explicitly mentioned in Quran, in several ayahs. Consider following ones as some instance:

1- 14:37 Prophet Abraham (Ibrahim pbuh)

> رَّبَّنَا إِنِّي أَسْكَنتُ مِن ذُرِّيَّتِي بِوَادٍ غَيْرِ ذِي زَرْعٍ
> عِندَ بَيْتِكَ الْمُحَرَّمِ رَبَّنَا لِيُقِيمُوا الصَّلَاةَ فَاجْعَلْ
> أَفْئِدَةً مِّنَ النَّاسِ تَهْوِي إِلَيْهِمْ وَارْزُقْهُم مِّنَ
> الثَّمَرَاتِ لَعَلَّهُمْ يَشْكُرُونَ
>
> Our Lord, I have settled some of my descendants in an uncultivated
> valley near Your sacred House, our Lord, that they may establish
> prayer. So make hearts among the people incline toward them and
> provide for them from the fruits that they might be grateful.

2- 14:40 Again Prophet Abraham (Ibrahim pbuh):

> رَبِّ اجْعَلْنِي مُقِيمَ الصَّلَاةِ وَمِن ذُرِّيَّتِي ۚ رَبَّنَا
> وَتَقَبَّلْ دُعَاءِ
>
> My Lord, make me an establisher of prayer, and [many] from my
> descendants. Our Lord, and accept my supplication.

3- 19:31 Saint Maryam (Mary):

> وَجَعَلَنِي مُبَارَكًا أَيْنَ مَا كُنتُ وَأَوْصَانِي بِالصَّلَاةِ
> وَالزَّكَاةِ مَا دُمْتُ حَيًّا
>
> And He has made me blessed wherever I am and has enjoined upon me
> prayer and zakah as long as I remain alive

Comment: he is referring to use of word "Salaat" in Arabic language.